# how can a void method communicate a value

Tags: java, jdbc

As a homework exercise (I'm a beginner) I had to write a Java program which accesses a database. The program can, e.g., insert new users, increment some fields etc. and I have methods such as: `addUser(User t)`, `deleteUser(User t)` and so on.
Many of these methods use `executeUpdate()`, which performs the update and returns an integer, namely the number of lines in the database affected by the update. 
In the corresponding test methods (using Junit5) I use this integer value for checks. **My question is: what is the best way to communicate to the test method the number of rows affected?**

What I have in place now is (in synthesis) as follows:

```
public class UserDaoImpl{ 
  public Integer rowsAffectedByLastUpdate;
  ...
  public void addUser(UserDto user) {
     ...
     rowsAffectedByLastUpdate = prep.executeUpdate();
     ...
  }
}
```

So I made `rowsAffectedByLastUpdate` a class variable which I then can access from elsewhere (I actually declare it private and use a getter, but the idea is the same). This works for the purposes of the exercice, but it was pointed out to me that in a multithreaded context this approach won't work anymore.

I could simply modify the method from `void addUser` to `Integer addUser`, but I hesitate because my class `UserDaoImpl` for database access implements an interface (which should not be database-specific) and in it `addUser` is declared as `void`. Is there any other, better way of achieving what I want?

Comment: *"So I made `rowsAffectedByLastUpdate` a class variable"* - bad idea! Now your `UserDaoImpl` has mutable state, which is a very bad idea for a service class. Do you actually want feedback from the `addUser` method -> yes: change the interface, no: don't change. I do not see how this question relates to any unit test. A unit test should mock the database anyway or have an in memory one and checks that the persisted data is correct,

Comment: thanks! I understand now.